# Подделка писем. Как защищаться

Tags: smtp, email

Кинули сайт https://emkei.cz/
Через него отправляю письма от имени всех своих сайтов.

DKIM, DMARC, SPF - настроены корректно.

Подскажите, на что обратить внимание в конфигурации сервера и как исключить отправку подложных писем ?

Comment: Если DKIM, DMARC, SPF есть, то этого достаточно

Comment: ну значит недостаточно (

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что через emkei.cz можно отправить поддельное письмо? Значит одно из двух: или вы всё-таки настроили DKIM, DMARC, SPF некорректно, или получатель письма их просто игнорирует и не выполняет необходимые проверки

Comment: Да, сам себе отправляю ..  
можете подсказать , как проверить корректно ли указаны эти параметры ? 
Я через сервисы проверок вставляю, они выводят, что записи есть, а вот правильно или нет - не пишут..

Comment: было правило 
`v=DMARC1; p=none; aspf=r; sp=none`
изменил его на 
`v=DMARC1; p=reject; adkim=s; aspf=s;`

проблема вроде решилась

Comment: Если вы не уверены в том что вы делаете, лучше поставьте `p=quarantine`

Comment: сделал поспешный вывод. Все равно письма отправляются

Comment: Отправляться они будут всегда (это технически невозможно ограничить), их должен фильтровать получатель в соответствии с правилами DMARC. Вы уверены, что получатель понимает DMARC?

Comment: Да, я накосячил, DMARC запись есть. Попробовал отправить письмо себе тоже на mail.ru — оно не пришло. Видимо, всё настроено корректно